# Wrap child textviews if they don't fit

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-view, textview

I have seen a couple of SO questions none of them worked for me.
e.g. [Android: How to wrap a layout to its views without exceeding a fixed size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13911128/android-how-to-wrap-a-layout-to-its-views-without-exceeding-a-fixed-size)

This is my current layout.

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/dummy_wrapper"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/eventTitleList"
        android:layout_below="@+id/eventTitleList"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/time"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="Today at 7:00pm - 9:30pm"
            android:textColor="#666666"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="\@ Museum" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

The objects are now side by side. If the width of the `dummy_wrapper` is "small" and the `name` is several words it will be "elipsize-d" (`...` added at the end of it and hide the words that cannot be visible).

If I remove the `singleLine` the `name` will be wrapped itself.

I want:

1. If the parent is "big" enough in width have the childs side by side in one line.
2. If the parent is not big enough wrap the second child (`name`) below the first (`time`)
3. If the parent is not big enough and `name` has been wrapped but still doesn't fit, then be "elipsize-d".

I don't mind if there is a solution with other type of view than a LinearLayout. xml would be better than a java solution.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is a layout behavior that do not exist natively in any of the Default Android Layouts, you would have to go for either RelativeLayout/LinearLayout and programatically check the space available and do the proper calculations to validate the different scenarios you want to cover OR create your custom ViewGroup.

However, recently I was reading a book "Android Experts, Apress Editorial" where they explain how to create a custom Layout which behaves exactly in the way you want, I don't want to paste the code of how they did it here because of possible copyrights issues, but is the page 63, is very simple but requires a perfect understanding of Android Views/Layout.

Hope it Helps!

Regards!